# Class PEAR not found when executing phpcs on MAC (but it's in my include directory)

Tags: php, pear

I get those  errors when i run phpcs (the PHP_CodeSniffer pear  package) (which i need to use [PAReview.sh](http://drupal.org/project/pareviewsh)) on my MAC

> PHP Deprecated:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in usr/lib/php/PEAR/Frontend.php on line 91 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Class 'PEAR' not found in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/Frontend.php on
>   line 47

The basically on line 47 the PEAR class is extended. The strange thing is that i have the PEAR class here

> /usr/lib/php/PEAR.php
>   /usr/local/zend/share/pear/PEAR.php

but this is in my include path

> include_path='.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear:/usr/lib/php'

What is worng?

Comment: 1) It may be in your include path, but did you actually `include` it? Have you got an autoloader? If so, does it work? 2) I think it is still the case that into order to extend a class, that class must already be loaded. Make sure you haven't declared your class which extends PEAR before you declared PEAR itself.

Comment: @DaveRandom i'm just trying to run another pear script, PHP_CodeSniffer

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `include_path` has a file named `PEAR.php` (case in-sensitive on Mac), which does not contain the `class PEAR` definition. I'd look through each of the directories in your `include_path` and see if there's another file that it is pulling in before the correct PEAR.php file (make sure you look in the current working directory as well, because you have `.` in your path).